# Google Pubsub: UNAVAILABLE: The service was unable to fulfill your request

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using the java library to subscribe to a subscription from my code. Using sbt:
`"com.google.cloud" % "google-cloud-pubsub" % "0.24.0-beta"`

I followed this guide to write a subscriber: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull

```
 val projectId = "test-topic"
 val subscriptionId = "test-sub"

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
 val subscriptionName = SubscriptionName.create(projectId, subscriptionId)
 val subscriber = Subscriber.defaultBuilder(subscriptionName, new PastEventMessageReceiver()).build()
 subscriber.startAsync()
 System.in.read()
}


class PastEventMessageReceiver extends MessageReceiver {
  override def receiveMessage(message: PubsubMessage, consumer: AckReplyConsumer): Unit = {
  println(message)
  consumer.ack()
}
```

It works great, I am able to pull published messaged but I keep seeing this error in my log multiple times per minute.

```
 com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.StreamingSubscriberConnection$1 onFailure
WARNING: Terminated streaming with exception
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: The service was unable to fulfill your request. Please try again. [code=8a75]
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:526)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:385)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:422)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:61)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:504)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:425)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:536)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I first run the app there is a small delay (around 1-2 mins) where I don't see that error, after the delay I see it multiple times per minute. My application seems to still able to pull messages tough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This message is an internal error in the Google Cloud Pub/Sub library that happens when there is a disconnection or retryable error in a request sent to the Pub/Sub server. The client library should seamlessly recreate connections and retry requests on these errors. In version 0.26.0-beta and later of the client library, these errors should no longer print out in the log unless you [have the log level set to FINE](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/commit/540734e6e9bce69f47854d2aabfbe61f1ac53631#diff-a876d55b1b7adce753a2915708a68ee8). In general, messages should still continue to be sent to your MessageReceiver after this error occurs. Any error that is not retryable by the client library itself, e.g., when a subscription is not found, is propagated back to the caller.